# Single channel png displayed with colors

Tags: matlab, png

I'm checking out the ground truth segmentation masks of the [pascal voc 2012 dataset](http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/voc2012/). These are single channel 8-bit uint png files. However when I open these images in either the file browser (nautilus) or the image viewer (eog) they are displayed in colors.
Shouldn't it be displayed in grayscale?
When I store an image as single channel 8-bit uint png file using Matlab, it is displayed in grayscale as expected. What is the difference are there different types of png files?
How can I store it such that my image viewer displays them in colors?

This is the original single channel png:
[image: this is the original single channel png]

This is the result after `imread` and `imwrite`. Note that NO channel has been added / removed:
[image: this is the result after <code>imread</code> and <code>imwrite</code> NO channel had been added / removed]

Comment: Reversing the question: if these images are displayed in colors outside Matlab, the must be 3-channel images (RGB). Why are you sure that they are single-channel?

Comment: Because when I load them into Matlab using `imread` they are displayed  as single channel uint8. I'll give an example above.

Comment: doubleclicking the file in MATLAB ambient, this paricular image contains 1 channel but also a 3-channel colormap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your image files contain [indexed images](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html#f2-155), with an M-by-N index matrix and a P-by-3 colormap matrix. How can you tell? You need to get the second output from [`imread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) when loading your images:

```
[img, cmap] = imread('zuIra.png');
if isempty(cmap)
  % Process data as a grayscale or RGB image
else
  % Process data as an indexed image
end
```

If `cmap` is empty, your data is either an M-by-N [grayscale intensity image](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html#f2-175) or an M-by-N-by-3 [Truecolor RGB image](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html#f2-12468). Otherwise, you're dealing with an indexed color image, and will have to use both pieces of data in any processing of your image, such as viewing it with [`imshow`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html):

```
imshow(img, cmap);
```

Or when resaving the data with [`imwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html):

```
imwrite(img, cmap, 'outfile.png');
```

If you would rather deal with a single image data matrix (which can make processing easier in some cases), you can convert the indexed image data and associated colormap into an RGB image with [`ind2rgb`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2rgb.html):

```
imgRGB = ind2rgb(img, cmap);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are dealing with an `1 to 8 bits` (variable) per pixel PNG with `indexed colors`.

When a format uses this technique, color information is not directly stored into the the image pixel data, but in a separate piece of data called `palette`. A `palette` can be defined as a predefined array of colors in which each element defines the trichromatic representation (`RGB`) of a specific color (`8 bits` per channel, for a total of `24 bits`).

The image pixel data does not contain the full specification of a color in the `RGB` form, but only the indices to the palette colors. Of course, the `palette` must contain one entry for each pixel color present in the image.

This approach can be seen as a form of compression, in which only a limited set of colors is available in order to save up memory/storage and speed up the display of the image.

Long story short, the result of your `imread` call is not returning you the color information of the image. Your array contains the indices to the PNG palette elements.

**Example**

Let's say that you have n indexed PNG that has a width of 3 pixels and a height of 1 pixel. The first pixel is pure red, the second pixel is pure green and the third pixel is pure blue.

In the PNG binary data, the `PLTE` chunk will contain the following color definitions:

```
[255 0 0] % Pure Red
[0 255 0] % Pure Green
[0 0 255] % Pure Blue
```

and the `IHDR` chunk will define a single channel with the following data:

```
0 1 2

% 0 = index to the first palette color, pure red
% 1 = index to the second palette color, pure green
% 2 = index to the third palette color, pure blue
```