# Convert RGB image into indexed image and save it

Tags: matlab, image-processing, png

I have an RGB image. So when I do `[image2, map] = imread('image.png')` in Matlab I get `[]` for map as expected. I want to convert that RGB image to an indexed image. I want to save it as an indexed image with one channel and see colours like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47438654/single-channel-png-displayed-with-colors).

Referring [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2ind.html#mw_b85c67f2-5c64-40c7-a5ba-c092064132d6) I used the following code in Matlab.

```
image2 = imread('image.png');
IND = rgb2ind(image2,256);
imwrite(IND, 'imageIndexed.png')
```

But what is saved is a grey-scale image. And when I read it back still the map is `[]`. I want to write it so that it will be a colour image and when I use `[image2, map] = imread('image.png')` next time, map won't be `[]`. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

- Convert image from RGB to indexed image with 2 color:

  ```
  [X, cmap] = rgb2ind(RGB, 2);
  ```
- Replace indices of color map to black and white:

  ```
  cmap(1, 1:3) = [0, 0, 0]; %Fist color is black
  cmap(2, 1:3) = [1, 1, 1]; %Second color is white
  ```
- Write indexed image (and map) to PNG file:

  ```
  imwrite(X, cmap, 'K.png');
  ```

Pay attention: you need to write the matrix and the color map, when writing and indexed image to file.

- Read image (and map) from PNG file, and convert it to RGB image:

  ```
  [I, cmap2] = imread('K.png');
  L = ind2rgb(I, cmap2);
  ```

---

Here is a code sample:

```
RGB = imresize(imread('peppers.png'), 0.5);   %Read input RGB image.

%Convert image to indexed image with 2 color.
[X, cmap] = rgb2ind(RGB, 2);
J = ind2rgb(X, cmap);

%Replace indices of color map:
cmap(1, 1:3) = [0, 0, 0]; %Fist color is black
cmap(2, 1:3) = [1, 1, 1]; %Second color is white

K = ind2rgb(X, cmap);

figure;imshow(RGB);
figure;imshow(J);
figure;imshow(K);

imwrite(X, cmap, 'K.png');

[I, cmap2] = imread('K.png');
L = ind2rgb(I, cmap2);
figure;imshow(L);
```

---

For completion, here is an example using your [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47438654/single-channel-png-displayed-with-colors):

```
[webX, web_cmap] = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuIra.png');   %Read input image and color map.
RGB = ind2rgb(webX, web_cmap);

%Convert image to indexed image with 4 colors.
[X, cmap] = rgb2ind(RGB, 4);

%Collect histogram
H = histogram(X, 4);
H = H.Values';

%Replace indices of color map: set the color with minimal pixels to white, and other to black.
cmap(H == min(H), :) = 1; %Fist color is black
cmap(H ~= min(H), :) = 0; %Set other three colors to black

%Convert to RGB
bwRGB = ind2rgb(X, cmap);

%Convert to indexed image with only 2 colors:
[X, cmap] = rgb2ind(bwRGB, 2);

imwrite(X, cmap, 'K.png');

[I, cmap2] = imread('K.png');
L = ind2rgb(I, cmap2);
figure;imshow(L);
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it works ^_^ I gave that link just to show what I want. If I have more than two colours, I can do "bwRGB = ind2rgb(X, cmap);" after "H = H.Values';"  right?

Comment: Yes, you can also skip the part with the `histogram`, I was just playing a little.